# Counting Total Number of Non-Equivalent Configurations in a 2-D Grid

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming, recursion, divide-and-conquer

This is a challenging question I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to solve via programming, math or both.

Suppose you're given a 2D grid, whose width and height, $w$ and $h$, can each range from $1$ thru $12$ inclusive. Each cell in this grid can be in any of $k$ states (where $k$ ranges from $2$ thru $20$).

The problem is to find the total number of distinct (non-equivalent) state configurations of this grid.

Definition: Two configurations of a grid, $c_1$ and $c_2$, are deemed "equivalent" if it is possible to change $c_1$ to $c_2$ by swapping any pair of rows and/or any pair of columns (you can perform the swap operation as many times as you want).

To take an example, let's consider a grid with $w=2$, $h=2$, and $k=2$. We will represent each of the two states as $0$ and $1$ respectively.

One possible configuration of the grid is one where all the cells are in state $0$:

00
00

You could swap any rows and/or columns without changing anything. So the above counts as 1 configuration.

Another configuration is where only 1 cell is in state $1$. There are 4 possible arrangements:

01 10 00 00
00 00 01 10

But note that all of the 4 arrangements are "equivalent", because you can get any of the arrangements by swapping rows and/or columns. So the above counts as 1 configuration.

Next, exactly 2 cells are in state $1$:

11 00
00 11

Another (non-equivalent) way in which 2 cells are in state $1$:

10 01
10 01

And yet another:

10 01
01 10

So there are 3 non-equivalent configurations in which exactly 2 cells are in state $1$.

Next, exactly 3 cells are in state $1$:

10 01 11 11
11 11 10 01

1 configuration, just as in the case where only 1 cell was in state $1$.

Finally, all 4 cells are in state $1$:

11
11

1 configuration, just as in the case where all 4 cells were in state $0$.

So, counting them up, there are exactly $7$ distinct configurations for the case where $w=2, h=2, k=2$.

For reference, here are some brute-force test cases I ran on some additional examples (where the w,h,k values are fairly small):

w=2,h=1,k=1 Answer: 1
w=2,h=1,k=2 Answer: 3
w=2,h=1,k=3 Answer: 6
w=2,h=1,k=4 Answer: 10
w=2,h=1,k=5 Answer: 15
w=2,h=1,k=6 Answer: 21
...
So at least when w, h are fixed at 1,2 (or at 2,1), the pattern seems pretty obvious as k increases. Here is another suite of test cases for w=2, h=2:

w=2,h=2,k=1 Answer: 1
w=2,h=2,k=2 Answer: 7
w=2,h=2,k=3 Answer: 27
w=2,h=2,k=4 Answer: 76
w=2,h=2,k=5 Answer: 175
w=2,h=2,k=6 Answer: 351
...
This is much less obvious to me. If there is a pattern, I'm unsure how to find it.

One more suite of test cases for good measure:

w=2,h=3,k=1 Answer: 1
w=2,h=3,k=2 Answer: 13
w=2,h=3,k=3 Answer: 92
w=2,h=3,k=4 Answer: 430
w=2,h=3,k=5 Answer: 1505
...
yep I'm lost as to what insight if any can be gained.

So, for some arbitrary $w,h,k$, I'm wondering whether there is some type of closed-form formula or perhaps a way to get the answer via dynamic programming/recursion or perhaps divide-and-conquer? I've tried a few of these approaches and didn't really see any obvious breakthrough. The answers get very large very quickly (for example, for $w=2,h=3,k=4$, the answer is 430). I can only imagine how large the answer would be for, say, $w=12,h=12,k=20$.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Can we put a grid into canonical form by sorting the rows (in lexicographic order), then sorting the columns (in lexicographic order), and repeating until we reach a fixpoint?  If so, the problem reduces to counting the number of grids that are in canonical form.  2. Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108862/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69095/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Can I ask, what's the source where you encountered this problem?  Is this from an open programming contest or assignment?  Giving credit and linking to the source of the problem is a [nice way to acknowledge others](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Burnside's lemma will work, but the solution is not very beautiful so I hope there's a better one. According to Burnside's lemma, the answer is  $\sum\frac{k^f}{w!h!}$ where $f$ is the "degree of freedom" under each permutation, i.e. the free variables you can choose among $k$ options. To count this, consider permutation in each dimension in cycle notation. Then $f=\sum gcd(l_w,l_h)$ where $l$ is the length of each cycle. The number of "partition" is not too much so you can enumerate possible partition and compute the number of permutations corresponding to each partition.

Comment: D.W.: noted and sorry about that. Btw, this was a conceptual interview question that I faced recently, not a contest or assignment. Though I'm not required to solve it at this point, I'm curious nonetheless. I'll look up Burnside's lemma in the meantime.

Comment: Am I the only one who immediately thinks of a Sudoku?

Comment: Another possible approach is dynamic programming. Like what D.W. said, we can convert each grid to its canonical form and enumerate it. For example, find the row whose sorted form has the smallest lexicographical order, put it at the first, and sort columns. Then choose the second row in the same way, but this time sorting is only allowed in columns which are tied in the first row, and so on. This gives a canonical form and a straightforward DP solution: adding rows one by one. But the problem is how to bound the number of states representing restrictions from previous rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will use [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), plus some additional optimizations.

Note that row swaps and column swaps commute, so the group of allowable transformations to the grid is exactly $G = S_w \times S_h$, where $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ symbols.  Note that $G$ embeds in $S_{wh}$ via a canonical embedding $\varphi : G \to S_{wh}$, given by $\varphi(\pi,\sigma) = \tau$ where $\tau$ is defined by $\tau(i,j) = (\pi(i), \sigma(j))$.  Therefore, we will think of $G$ simultaneously as the direct product $S_w \times S_h$ and also as a subgroup of $S_{wh}$.

Now let's count the number of grids that are fixed by a group element $g=(\pi,\sigma) \in G$.  Define the *cycle type* of a permutation $\pi$ to be the multiset of lengths of the cycles in the [cycle decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) of $\pi$.  If $\pi \in S_n$, the cycle type of $\pi$ is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$.  With this in mind, we will let $\ell(\pi)$ denote the cycle type of $\pi \in S_w$ and $\ell(\sigma)$ the cycle type of $\sigma \in S_h$.  Finally, let $\ell((\pi,\sigma))$ denote the cycle type of $(\pi,\sigma)$, thinking of $(\pi,\sigma)$ as an element of $S_{wh}$.

We can express $\ell((\pi,\sigma))$ in terms of $\ell(\pi)$ and $\ell(\sigma)$.  Let $x,y$ range over all $x \in \ell(\pi), y \in \ell(\sigma)$.  For each $x,y$, $\ell((\pi,\sigma))$ has $\gcd(x,y)$ copies of $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$.  It follows that

$$|\ell((\pi,\sigma))| = \sum_{x \in \ell(\pi)} \sum_{y \in \ell(\sigma)} m_x n_y \gcd(x,y),$$

where $x,y$ range over all distinct values (without repetition), and $m_x$ is the multiplicity of $x$ in $\ell(\pi)$ (the number of times $x$ appears in $\ell(\pi)$) and $n_y$ is the multiplicity of $y$ in $\ell(\sigma)$.

Now the number of grids that are fixed by $(\pi,\sigma)$ is

$$f(\pi,\sigma) = k^{|\ell((\pi,\sigma))|},$$

where $|\ell((\pi,\sigma))|$ counts the number of cycles in $(\pi,\sigma) \in G$ (multiplicities are counted).  By the above formula for $|\ell((\pi,\sigma))|$, we see that

$$f(\pi,\sigma) = k^{\sum_{x \in \ell(\pi)} \sum_{y \in \ell(\sigma)} m_x n_y \gcd(x,y)}.$$

To apply Burnside's lemma, it remains to sum $f(g)$ over all elements $g \in G$, as Burnside's lemma tells us that the total number of non-equivalent grids is

$$N = {1 \over |G|} \sum_{g \in G} f(g) = {1 \over w! h!} \sum_{g \in G} f(g).$$

In principle, we could compute this sum by enumerating all $w! h!$ elements in $G$, then evaluating $f$ on each, and summing the result.

It turns out this can be optimized further, as $f(\pi,\sigma)$ depends only on $\ell(\pi)$ and $\ell(\sigma)$, but not on any other aspect of $\pi$ or $\sigma$.  Thus, we can more efficiently evaluate the sum using the formula

$$\sum_{g \in G} f(g) = \sum_{P,Q} N(P,Q) \times k^{\sum_{x \in P} \sum_{y \in Q} \gcd(x,y)},$$

where the inner sum ranges over all partitions $P$ of $w$ and all partitions $Q$ of $h$, and where we define

$$N(P,Q) = |\{(\pi,\sigma) \in G : \ell(\pi)=P, \ell(\sigma)=Q\}|$$

to count the number of group elements of $G$ whose cycle types are $P,Q$.  Now we have

$$N(P,Q) = N_w(P) \times N_h(Q),$$

where $N_w(P) = |\{\pi \in S_w : \ell(\pi)=P\}|$ is the number of permutations in $S_w$ with cycle type $P$, and similarly $N_h(Q)$ is the number of permutations in $S_h$ with cycle type $Q$.  Finally, there is a [known formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37860/14578) to compute $n_w(P)$ for any desired partition $P$; it is

$$N_w(P) = {w! \over \prod_{x \in P} m_x! x^{m_x}},$$

where $x$ ranges over the distinct elements of $P$ and $m_x$ is the multiplicity of $x$ in $P$ (the number of times $x$ appears in $P$).

Plugging in, we find that the total number of non-equivalent grids is given by

$$N = \sum_{P,Q} {k^{\sum_{x \in P} \sum_{y \in Q} m_x n_y \gcd(x,y)} \over \prod_{x \in P} m_x! x^{m_x} \prod_{y \in Q} n_y! y^{n_y}}.$$

As before, in this formula $x,y$ range over distinct values, $m_x$ is the multiplicity of $x$ in $P$, and $n_y$ is the multiplicity of $y$ in $Q$.

This can be computed by two nested for-loops that iterate over all partitions $P$ of $w$ and all partitions $Q$ of $h$.

What is the running time of this algorithm?  The  asymptotic running time is approximately $O(p(w) p(h))$, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of the integer $n$.  [It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas) that asymptotically $p(n) = O(\exp\{\pi \sqrt{2n/3} \})$, so it follows that the asymptotic running time of this algorithm is approximately $O(\exp\{\pi \sqrt{2/3} (\sqrt{w}+\sqrt{h})\})$, or equivalently, approximately $O(2^{3.7(\sqrt{w}+\sqrt{h})})$.  This should allow you to handle the full range of values $1 \le w,h \le 12$, as for that range we have $\sqrt{w}+\sqrt{h} < 7$ and $2^{3.7 \times 7} \approx 2^{26}$ is not too large.

Comment: Nice! But some points should be fixed: 1. $\operatorname{lcm} (x,y)$ appears $\gcd(x,y)$ times in $l((\pi,\sigma))$. This is crucial. 2.$f=k^e$ where $e$ is the number of cycle. In your formula you write it as the sum of cycle length but this is always $hw$. 3. You miss $k$ in your final formula.

Comment: Thank you. This deserves a careful viewing. I'll be back with any follow-up questions once I understand all the notations.

Comment: @aaaaajack, Oh my yes.  Thank you for spotting all those errors!  I think I've fixed them now, but if you see any other mistakes, let me know.  Thank you again!

Comment: I must be missing something trivial here, but this clearly doesn't work for k=1 and I suspect for other values as well, since we end up summing up non-zero values whose total count depends on the number of partitions.

Comment: Yeah, something not adding up here. For example for w=2,h=2,k=2 the final sum ends up 2^gcd(2,2)/2*2 + 2^(gcd(2,1)+gcd(2,1))/2*1*1 + 2^(gcd(1,2)+gcd(1,2))/1*1*2 + 2^(gcd(1,1)+gcd(1,1)+gcd(1,1)+gcd(1,1))/1*1*1*1 = 21, should be 7

Comment: @ŠimonTóth, ok.  Well, this answer is over 4 years old, and I don't have time to check every line carefully.  Perhaps you could work through the reasoning and help us figure out where I went wrong, whether there is a way to repair it, or whether this just needs to be deleted?  Thank you for your review of it.

Comment: Sadly, I don't quite follow several steps. I don't understand the step that leads to the k to the power of gcd expression. And I also suspect the step evaluating nw(P) is ignoring symmetries, and the product should be x^ax*ax! where ax is the count of x in the partition.

Comment: @ŠimonTóth, OK, I've reviewed this carefully.  You correctly spotted the problem.  Thank you!  I've gone through the entire answer and I think I've fixed the problem.  Check it now?  Does it look correct now?

Comment: @D.W. Still seems to be incorrect. w=2, h=3, k=4 should be 430, this returns 390. I really don't think the k^sum.... formula is correct.

Comment: @D.W. One more thing, this formula is happy to generate rational numbers. I would expect the contribution from each combination of partitions to be always a whole number.

Comment: @D.W. OK, another example. So for w=2, h=3, k=5 the result for the partitions [2] and [3] we end up with 5^1/2*3 = 5/6 which should clearly be 1, not 5/6. The 6 makes sense to me, so again, I think the k^sum... is incorrect.